# Merge multiple object arrays and removing duplicates based on optional property

Tags: node.js, typescript, lodash

Say if there are arrays like:

```
const arr1 = [
   { "id": "1", "type": "sales" },
   { "id": "2", "type": "finance" }
]

const arr2 = [
   { "type": "sales" },
   { "id": "2", "type": "finance" }
]

const arr3 = [
   { "id": "1", "type": "sales" },
   { "type": "sales" },
   { "type": "finance" }
]
```

As you can see, `id` is optional. I need to merge arrays in such way that uniqueness should be based on `id` if present, else entire rest of the object.
ex. here merged array would be:

```
[ 
  { "id": "1", "type": "sales" }, 
  { "type": "sales" }, 
  { "id": "2", "type": "finance" }, 
  { "type": "finance" } 
]
```

loadash has `.unionBy` but optional uniqueness doesn't work.

```
const result = _.unionBy(arr1, arr2, arr3, 'id')
```

Probably I have to iterate through each, but I was wondering if there is any simpler alternative for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `_.unionBy` you can use [`_.unionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/#unionWith) which accepts a custom comparator. The logic for comparison is:

1. Compare by ID if both items have an ID.
2. Compare by type if both items *do not* have an ID.
3. Consider them different if one has an ID the other not.

```js
const arr1 = [
   { "id": "1", "type": "sales" },
   { "id": "2", "type": "finance" }
]

const arr2 = [
   { "type": "sales" },
   { "id": "2", "type": "finance" }
]

const arr3 = [
   { "id": "1", "type": "sales" },
   { "type": "sales" },
   { "type": "finance" }
]

const result = _.unionWith(arr1, arr2, arr3, (item1, item2) => {
  const item1HasId = _.has(item1, "id");
  const item2HasId = _.has(item2, "id");
  
  if (item1HasId && item2HasId) //if both have ID...
    return item1.id === item2.id; // ...compare by ID
    
  if (!item1HasId && !item2HasId) //if neither has ID...
    return item1.type === item2.type; // ...compare by type
    
  return false; // otherwise not equal
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```